# Alexa skill to access a website

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have recently strated learning about Alexa skills. I was wondering if we could access different websites using alexa. For example, *"Alexa, show me my facebook notifications"*

So far I have seen examples of how we can create WebAPIs using Amazon API Gateway. But can we access a different website or a blog with GET or POST method that is not using Amazon API Gateway.

Also, what authorizations will be needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, "Alexa, show me my facebook notifications"

Yes, it is possible to have that kind of functionality.

Currently, I'm developing with nodejs and use the [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module for making HTTP request to my server.

Also, there is a nice [tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a9ef18b2-ef68-44d4-86eb-dbdb293853bb/alexa-skill-recipe-making-http-requests-to-get-data-from-an-external-api) using the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm module.

Comment: Thanks but the tutorial you linked is out dated now (it does not use SDK v2). Any link that show how to handle http request with SDK v2 ? (using canHandle() and handle() functions)